# Laravel Telescope - How to add tags to a specific cache for tracking its behaviour

Tags: laravel, debugging, laravel-telescope

Laravel Telescope seems to be a useful tool to control different requests.

One use I have in mind is to be able to track how often a cache is used.

Imagine a big application and you try to find out if it is worth to store certain database queries in the cache or if the queries in general do not occur too often. Especially if you want to improve an existing project and you want to try out separately if caching a specific database query makes sense.

Therefore I would like to be able to search for the specific cache key or a telescope tag when calling the cache.

If an application already has thousands of cache calls every day, it will probably be hard to search for a specific cache tag in Telescope without this capability.

Telescope's search box under "Cache" doesn't seem to inherently allow you to search for results using the cache key.

Does anyone here have experience how to do this correctly?

```
    $no_track_needed = cache()->remember("no_track_needed", 20, function() {
        return "Hello World";
    });

    $track_this = cache()->remember("track_this", 120, function() {
        return "Hello Telescope";
    });
```

Sincerely and thank you for reading through

I have tried via the Laravel documentation to recreate such behavior, but then all cache keys are tagged instead of just the cache keys I want. Unfortunately I don't have much experience with this.